How to add locale to p-calendar in angular 17
I am working on an application where I am trying to add a locale but not working for me. Below is my code
frLocale: any = {
    firstDayOfWeek: 1,
    dayNames: ["Dimanche", "Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi"],
    dayNamesShort: ["Dim", "Lun", "Mar", "Mer", "Jeu", "Ven", "Sam"],
    dayNamesMin: ["Di", "Lu", "Ma", "Me", "Je", "Ve", "Sa"],
    monthNames: ["Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre"],
    monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Fév", "Mar", "Avr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aoû", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Déc"],
    today: 'Aujourd\'hui',
    clear: 'Effacer',
    dateFormat: 'mm/yy' // Ensure this matches the dateFormat you want
};


HTML Code

<p-calendar id="cCExpDate"  [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="2020:2030" dateFormat="mm/yy"  [view]="'month'" [locale]="frLocale"  formControlName="cCExpDate"></p-calendar>

